# DoesNotExist at /delete/64 list matching query does not exist.django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i'm creating todo list its fine working but when i double click so it shows me an error here is the screenshot [image]

here is my views.py code https://www.onlinegdb.com/edit/SJjz-d1aD

Comment: Please write https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  on site

Comment: where i wan't to add this

Comment: Edit your question to include relevant details